# OpenGL game engine

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, opengl

I'm making a C++ game engine for entertainment and am using OpenGL to render my stuff. I made a batch renderer that was able to render 50K sprites with 300 FPS (untextured). My old setup that was able to run with 300 FPS was the following:

I had a class called `Renderable2D`, which held everything:

```
class Renderable2D
{
protected:
    vec3f m_Position;
    vec2f m_Size;
    vec4f m_Color;
    const Texture2D * m_Texture;
    std::vector<vec2f> m_TexCoords;

protected:
    Renderable2D() { }

public:
    Renderable2D(vec3f position, vec2f size, vec4f color)
        : m_Position(position), m_Size(size), m_Color(color), m_Texture(nullptr)
    {
        m_TexCoords.push_back(vec2f(0, 0));
        m_TexCoords.push_back(vec2f(0, 1));
        m_TexCoords.push_back(vec2f(1, 1));
        m_TexCoords.push_back(vec2f(1, 0));
    }

    virtual ~Renderable2D()
    { }

    inline virtual void Submit(Renderer2D * renderer) const
    {
        renderer->Submit(*this);
    }

    inline const vec3f& GetPosition() const { return m_Position; }
    inline const vec2f& GetSize() const { return m_Size; }
    inline const vec4f& GetColor() const { return m_Color; }
    inline const std::vector<vec2f>& GetTexCoords() const { return m_TexCoords; }

    inline const GLuint GetTextureID() const { return (m_Texture == nullptr ? 0 : m_Texture->GetTextureID()); }
};
```

Basically, this was a class that held everything: the texture coordinates (if it had any), the color, position and size. My batch renderer had a method to draw any `Renderable2D` based on this class:

```
void BatchRenderer::Submit(const Renderable2D& renderable)
{
    const vec3f& position = renderable.GetPosition();
    const vec2f& size = renderable.GetSize();
    const unsigned int color = renderable.GetColor();
    const std::vector<vec2f>& texCoords = renderable.GetTexCoords();
    const GLuint tid = renderable.GetTextureID();

    float ts = 0.0f;
    if (tid > 0)
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m_TextureSlots.size(); i++)
        {
            if (m_TextureSlots[i] == tid)
            {
                ts = (float)(i + 1);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            if (m_TextureSlots.size() >= 32)
            {
                End();
                Flush();
                Begin();
            }

        m_TextureSlots.push_back(tid);
        ts = (float)(m_TextureSlots.size());
        }
    }

    Maths::vec3f _tpos = *m_TransformationBack * position;

    m_Buffer->Position = _tpos;
    m_Buffer->TexCoord = texCoords[0];
    m_Buffer->TexID = ts;
    m_Buffer->Color = color;
    m_Buffer++;

    _tpos.y += size.y;

    m_Buffer->Position = _tpos;
    m_Buffer->TexCoord = texCoords[1];
    m_Buffer->TexID = ts;
    m_Buffer->Color = color;
    m_Buffer++;

    _tpos.x += size.x;

    m_Buffer->Position = _tpos;
    m_Buffer->TexCoord = texCoords[2];
    m_Buffer->TexID = ts;
    m_Buffer->Color = color;
    m_Buffer++;

    _tpos.y -= size.y;

    m_Buffer->Position = _tpos;
    m_Buffer->TexCoord = texCoords[3];
    m_Buffer->TexID = ts;
    m_Buffer->Color = color;
    m_Buffer++;

    m_IndexCount += 6;
}
```

I wanted to make this a bit nicer and faster, so I created subclasses for `renderable2D`. `Renderable2D` only had it's position and size. `Rectangle` (inherited from `Renderable2D`) had color too, and Sprite had a texture and texture coords. I think this is a bit more categorized and makes a simple colored rectangle less heavily-weighted (no texture coords). Then I overrode the `Renderable2D`'s submit method for both the rectangle and the sprite and created (which I thought were) optimized submit methods for my renderer. I've kept the original one, but overloaded the method, so I had:

```
void BatchRenderer::Submit(const vec2f& position, const vec2f& size, unsinged int color);
void BatchRenderer::Submit(const vec2f& position, const vec2f& size, GLuint textureID, const std::vector<vec2f>& textureCoords);
```

This way I didn't need to assign everything for `m_Buffer` and I could eliminate the `if` statement (`if (tid > 0)`) because now I knew when the renderable used a texture. I thought this would speed up the code, but it slowed it down to about half its speed (testing conditions were the same for the unoptimized and "optimized" code). Why did this refactor (which I think should speed up the code) slow it down? Less assignments, one less `if` statement, smaller data structures.

- `m_Buffer`: It's actually a vertex buffer object, it's named simply buffer because it's not only storing vertices, but colors, texture coordinates and texture IDs too. The `Submit` method basically writes mapped data to this buffer.
- `ts`: It stands for texture slot, yes it's a really bad naming, I should rename it. It's a float because OpenGL actually likes float more in a float buffer than an integer.
- `m_IndexCount`: The size of the index buffer. (Index of vertices)
- `Renderable2D`: I have a Submit method that just passes itself to the renderer. It's virtual on purpose. You don't send sprites directly to the renderer, because there are `Rendereable2D`s called `Group`s. They override the `Submit` method and sends their children instead.
- `m_Texture`: `Renderable2D` sets it as `nullptr` for now. There's a subclass called `Sprite` that's basically a constructor which sets the texture to the passed parameter. And my plan is to clean up `Renderable2D` from the things it doesn't need like texture, because sprite needs it really.

Comment: Impossible to tell without comparing both implementations. However, that would be of-topic in this site. What we can do is provide you a review for the code you have posted.

Comment: I could add a github link for the repo if it's not off-topic.

Comment: Yes, you can, but don't expect people to follow the link. Like I said, reviewers will focus on the code you post here.

Comment: Then I'll edit my post and add the "optimized" imlementation.

Comment: It would be best for you to just post the version you wish reviewed, unless both are relevant for the review.

Comment: Or you can post two distinct questions. The problem with posting two different implementations and asking "why is A slower than B" is that there is no clear answer to that without a lot of context and profiling data. All users can do is speculate. This kind of questions are not a good match for code review and are most often closed.

Comment: @CodezMe When you are looking at performance. Guessing will often make your code slower, you need to profile and see where your hotspots are. Without such profiling data, we can only speculate (which may or may not be accurate).

Comment: Which site would be appropriate to ask about performance issues based on the 2 implementations?

Answer (score 12):

A couple things I would have done differently, plus some other broader advices:

- `Renderable2D` seems to me is representing a single sprite, each sprite being a quadrilateral. In that case, you really don't need a variable amount of texture coordinates, but rather just 4. No need to use a `std::vector` in this case and force a heap allocation. Just use a plain array of `vec2f` or a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you are open to using C++11.
- You don't need to add `inline` when the method is defined directly inside the class body in the header file. That serves no practical purpose and only makes the code more verbose.
- Always favor the C++-style casts. [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) and friends will provide better compiler diagnostics if you attempt some unsafe cast.

Two bits of personal style:

- It is a common convention to name user defined types using `PascalCase`, like you already do, and variables and functions with `camelCase`, to differentiate both kinds of things. Actually, the idea is to name anything that can have its memory address take with `camelCase` and reserve the first letter capitalized for types.
- I find it better to place the **public** interface of a class first in the header file, to give it more emphasis. That's usually the part you and users of your code will be looking at more often. **protected** and **private** are implementation details, so shouldn't need to stand out as much.

Answer (score 8):

I concur with @glampert's suggestions. I have a few questions of my own.

**Naming**

What is the purpose of the `Submit()` method? What is it submitting? (I don't see any calls to OpenGL to submit vertex attribute data, for example.) Also, it appears to update the value of an internal pointer, `m_Buffer`. What is it a buffer of? Its name should reflect what it represents. Is it vertex data? If so, name it `m_VertexBuffer` or `m_SpriteBuffer` or whatever would be appropriate.

**Types**

In the `Submit()` method what is the purpose of `ts`? It's a `float` but you eventually assign `mBuffer->TexId` to the value of `ts`. But texture IDs are `GLuints`. Also, it appears to be an index in the array of texture slots, and not an actual texture ID as OpenGL knows it. If it's not actually the ID returned by `glGenTextures()` or some equivalent, I would not name it `TexID`. Maybe `TextureIndex` instead? And it's not likely a `float`, so make `ts` be the correct type, whether it's `GLuint` or just an `unsigned int`.

**Repetition**

You have almost identical code written 4 times:

```
m_Buffer->Position = _tpos;
m_Buffer->TexCoord = texCoords[0];
m_Buffer->TexID = ts;
m_Buffer->Color = color;
m_Buffer++;
```

Why not make that into a function and call it 4 times with the appropriate arguments instead of writing it out by hand 4 times?

**Miscellaneous**

What does the last line of `Submit()` do?

```
m_IndexCount += 6;
```

The code above it appears to be adding 4 entries to the m_Buffers list. Why does the index count increase by 6? What is its purpose?

In `Renderable2D`, you have a `Submit()` method that you pass a `Renderer2D` to. It simply calls `renderer->Submit(*this);`. That seems like a pointless method. Why doesn't the caller just call `renderer->Submit(*renderable);` and save 1 step?

**Memory**

How does one set `Renderable2D::m_Texture`? I see how to get it, but it doesn't get set in the constructor, it's `protected`, and there's no accessor to set it. (It's also never freed, which might be OK if another object owns it. If so, you might consider using a `std::shared_ptr` if you're in C++11.)

Comment: Actually the `m_IndexCount += 6` thing makes sense. OpenGL has something called [*indexed drawing*](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-9-vbo-indexing/), which is probably what that variable is about. I assume each sprite is comprised of 2 triangles, so it will add 6 indexes for each sprite, one per point, hence the `+= 6`.

Comment: Fair enough. If that's the case, it should be explained somewhere. I've done indexed drawing and it didn't even occur to me that this would have been related to that!

Comment: Yep, we are both guessing, really. Reviewing incomplete code is complicated, but that's the OPs loss for not posting more detail. Your answer is pretty good nonetheless.

Comment: Sorry I'll edit my post and explain.